# Can you save a certain character from dying in Minecraft Story Mode Episode 4?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

Is there any way to save Reuben in Episode 4?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://minecraftstorymode.wikia.com/wiki/Reuben_(Pig)) site, and my own experience, Reuben is destined to die no matter what.